# share cookie between nodejs and php

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I want to use SSL for nodejs to secure socketio communication, so I need to use SSL for both apache and node.

In order to have ability to share cookie between php and node, I have to use same domain name .

but if I can not use 443 for same domain that uses both nodejs and php same time.

how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a reverse proxy such as [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) to proxy requests to either Apache or node.

For the actual sharing of sessions between node and PHP (via redis) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795926/share-sessions-between-php-and-node/23796095#23796095).

Comment: when a user want to request XXXXX.com:443 , how haproxy want to know should it be for node or apache ?

Comment: You can use any criteria you want. It could be based on the requested path, an HTTP header that's present, etc.