# How can I parse PHP user details (session) to Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

so I have 2 pages:
Chat page which runs on Node.js and Socket.io (WebSockets).
And main page where user logins etc...
I want to make it so when user logins on main page -> it validates details -> then stores user ID in session and goes into chat where he's identified by his userID.

Oh yeah and user accounts are stored on MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* parse PHP (file-based) sessions from node with a module like [groan](https://github.com/mscdex/groan). However, a better solution is probably to use a better session store such as [redis](http://redis.io). An example of sharing sessions between node and PHP using redis can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796095/2050455).

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Cookies mechanism was created to communicate with different environments. Let's use it..

**PHP:**

Validate user data and save it into DB and then save `id` to cookies.

**NodeJS:**

Read that `id` from cookies and get data from DB (MySQL provider for nodejs)

Comment: I had that approach in mind but:
What stops user from modifying cookie, setting ID to other user and using his personality to chat?

Comment: Then you need to more advanced way -- tokens. Set ID and token (sha1 hash for example). Store both of these in DB and then try to find entry equals to it. Hacker will must to use brute-force attack (not dangerous) to hack this. You can even add expire time for tokens